# How to use data augmentation with cross validation

Tags: python, keras

I need to use data augmentation on what would be my training data from the data augmentation step. The problem is that i am using cross-validation, so i can't find a reference how to adjust my model to use data augmentation. My cross-validation is somewhat indexing by hand my data.

There is articles and general content about data augmentation, but very little and with no generalization for cross validation with data augmentation

I need to use data augmentation on training data by simply rotating and adding zoom, cross validate for the best weights and save them, but i wouldnt know how.

This example can be copy pasted for better reproducibility, in short how would i employ data augmentation and also save the weights with the best accuracy?

Comment: This seems to be a pretty specific problem. I might be unable to answer that without extensive (and time consuming) question modification. For the time being, it might be easier for you to see a [complete example of that](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning_with_hub).

Comment: I think that this is a misleading usage of cv... I suggest in your case to do hyperparam tuning with cv. you are simply choosing the portion of data where your model structure do better

Comment: I can't understand what you want. Does your code already implement data augmentation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When training machine learning models, you should not test model on the samples used during model training phase (if you care for realistic results).

**Cross validation** is a method for estimating model accuracy. The essence of the method is that you split your available labeled data into several parts (or *folds*), and then use one part as a test set, training the model on all the rest, and repeating this procedure for all parts one by one. This way you essentially test your model on all the available data, without hurting training too much. There is an implicit assumption that data distribution is the same in all folds. As a rule of thumb, the number of cross validation folds is  usually 5 or 7. This depends on the amount of the labeled data at one's disposal - if you have lots of data, you can afford to leave less data to train the model and increase test set size. The higher the number of folds, the better accuracy estimation you can achieve, as the training size part increases, and more time you have to invest into the procedure. In extreme case one have a leave-one-out training procedure: train on everything but one single sample, effectively making number of the folds equal to the number of data samples.

So for a 5-fold CV you train 5 different models, which have a a large overlap of the training data. As a result, you should get 5 models that have similar performance. (If it is not the case, you have a problem ;) ) After you have the test results, you **throw away all 5 models you have trained**, and train a new model on **all** the available data, assuming it's performance would be a mean of the values you've got during CV phase.

Now about the augmented data. You should not allow data obtained by augmentation of the training part leak into the test. Each data point created from the training part should be used only for training, same applies to the test set.

So you should split your original data into *k-folds* (for example using [KFold](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html#sklearn.model_selection.KFold) or [GroupKFold](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GroupKFold.html#sklearn.model_selection.GroupKFold)), then create augmented data for each fold and concatenate them to the original. Then you follow regular CV procedure.

In your case, you can simply pass each group (such as `x_group1`) through augmenting procedure before concatenating them, and you should be fine.

Please note, that splitting data in linear way can lead to unbalanced data sets and it is not the best way of splitting the data. You should consider functions I've mentioned above.

Comment: It does not really matter if want to use cross validation for accuracy estimation or hyperparameter tuning. The approach does not change: from all the available data you hold off a part to test/fine tune the model so it would be samples that the model did not see during its training (to prevent overfitting and  memorization). If you need to use augmentation, you treat the newly created samples the exact same way as real ones. So you create a test-train split, then augment training data, create a model, test/fine tune it on the hold-off part.

Comment: Please see [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/machinex-image-data-augmentation-using-keras-b459ef87cd22) and [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-configure-image-data-augmentation-when-training-deep-learning-neural-networks/)

Answer (score 0):

I used to do this with my project before. From my experience,

1. First, we split my dataset 5-fold using the sklearn library. Each fold has four portions as a training set and a portion as a validation set with different indexes.
2. Then, for each 5-fold iteration, we can create data augmentation with only a training set based on its indexes and concate them to the original training set.
3. Finally, all data augmentation will be augmented with the original training set in each fold, not leaking into the validation set.